# Multiple Audio, Live Smooth Streaming

Tags: c#, silverlight, iis-7, streaming, audio-streaming

I could not find any document which explains how to provide multiple audio streams for Live Smooth Streaming.

For example, in [Microsoft PDC](http://player.microsoftpdc.com/Session/19c4c834-3cae-408c-96f0-e87bfad92cff)'s streams, it is possible to select languages.

Does [SMF](http://smf.codeplex.com) provide this feature? If it is, how? How my isml file will look like?

Comment: SO Silverlight question #10,000. Congrats :)

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/558/getting-started-with-iis-smooth-streaming/) gives a sample for multiple languages for Audio in Smooth streaming.
If you are looking for this, please note that unlike video smooth streaming currently does not support multiple bit rates for audio.

Comment: Do you know how can I specifaclly say that "hey! these are my audios"?

Answer (score 0):

There is SmoothStreamingMediaElement.ManifestMerge event that enables adding additional streams to manifest loaded when opening media. This is called manifest merging and is described here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff432455%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

In SMF you can access SSME by IAdaptiveMediaPlugin.VisualElement interface. 
So if you have two live streaming endpoints:

AudioAndVideo.isml/Manifest (standard audio and video streams)

Audio2.isml/Manifest (second audio stream with dummy video streams)

you could open the first one and merge it with audio stream from the second one. This requires two encoding sessions of Expression Encoder.